# PayPal Python "return_url" not working properly with a function

Tags: python, paypal, kivy

I'm working on a Kivy app with PayPal integration. But I'm having a small issue with the `return_url` feature. I have it currently set to go to a function in my Python script. I didn't expect this to work but it did (kinda). It calls `self.Continue()` in the `return_url` line as soon as the button is pressed to go to the PayPal checkout instead of calling it after the customer has clicked on Continue on the PayPal page. Is there any way to fix this small issue? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Here's a sample of my .py it is helps

```
def Continue(self):
    self.manager.current = "main"

def PayPal(self):
    request.request_body({
                    "application_context": {
                        "return_url": self.Continue()},
    
    
                    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    
                    "purchase_units": [
                        {
                            "amount": {
                                "currency_code": "CAD",
                                "value": str(App.get_running_app().cart)
                            }
                        }
                    ]



            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal is external to your app, so return_url must be a string that is a URL that can be returned to. It should likely be a deeplink back to your app, which can then run your function based on that path that was returned to.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'll try to figure out how to do it. Thanks!